# Зачем нужен Dependency Injection контейнер?

Tags: проектирование, dependency-injection

Принцип Inversion of Control мне понятен и логичен, но зачем нужен DI я осознать не могу.
Пример:

```
public class Samurai 
{
    public IWeapon Weapon { get; private set; }
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon) 
    {
        this.Weapon = weapon;
    }
}
```

И тут мы где-то в одном месте программы внедряем зависимость между интерфейсом и конкретной реализацией. Т.е. при необходимости достаточно только тут подменить другую реализацию, например для тестирования или просто так. Здесь используется Ninject, но не суть важно какой фреймворк.

```
this.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
```

Окей, все хорошо, НО зачем нам нужен DI фреймворк, если мы можем сделать по сути тоже самое:

```
var samurai = new Samurai(new Sword());
```

Т.е. в конструктор мы точно так же, как и в примере с DI фреймворком можем подменить реализацию, изменив всего-лишь одно слово в одном месте.
Так в чем же тогда смысл DI контейнера? Извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый, я новичок.

Comment: Для декомпозиции кода, чтобы сложные вещи разбить на мелкие под-модули. Если эта штука не позволяет так сделать, то не пользуйтесь.

Comment: В реальных задачах место не одно и слов тоже по-более будет. Тут дело в замене одних реализаций на другие без переделки, перекомпиляции исходного кода, с последующей переустановкой программы. Просто готовится альтеративная реализация, устанавливается, подправляется конфигурация контейнера DI.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Можно еще попробовать на практике, понимание приходит быстрее. Создайте не одного самурая, а штук двадцать в разных файлах. Создайте помимо самурая еще штук десять разных классов и по пять экземпляров каждого. А теперь попробуйте подменить в них при передаче IWeapon класс Sword на что-то другое использую для этого внедрение зависимойстей и сравните с вариантом передачи в конструктор.

Answer (score 26):

**Inversion Of Control** - это принцип используемый для уменьшения связанности кода.

**Dependency Injection** - это один из способов реализации данного принципа в котором зависимости передаются через конструктор (как правило) или через установку свойств (реже).

**Ninject**, **Unity** и т.п. это **Dependency Injection Container** - инструмент для более простого применения **Dependency Injection**. Как правило он позволяет более удобно задавать композицию объектов, их время жизни, а так же перехват (interception).

Для применения **Dependency Injection** использование каких-либо фреймворков (контейнеров) не обязательно. Они лишь позволяют сделать это более удобно.

---

Чтобы было лучше понятно я попробую (совсем вкратце) описать преимущества DI-контейнера.

В указанном выше примере все достаточно просто. Существует всего несколько классов которые легко можно вручную скомпоновать вместе. В таком случае смысл в DI-контейнере действительно отсутствует и все можно сделать руками достаточно просто.

Но, когда проект становится больше, появляется больше объектов и их вложенность друг в друга становится глубже - управлять всем этим вручную становится достаточно сложно. Потому, что это будет требовать или написания большого объема кода либо собственного, встроенного фреймворка.

Контейнер, в свою очередь, позволяет:

1. Задавать различную конфигурацию и удобно ей управлять. Использовать различные соглашения, чтобы контейнер сам "подцеплял" нужные ему типы найденные по определенным условиям в проекте. Если конфигурация читается из внешнего файла (например xml), то поведение программы можно поменять без перекомпиляции. И т.д. и т.п.
2. Так как в сложных случаях может быть так, что объекты которые передаются как зависимости так же могут требовать для себя какие-то зависимости которые так же могут требовать для себя какие зависимости и т.д. реализовывать все это вручную будет трудоемко. Контейнер же с легкостью сделает это все самостоятельно.
3. Позволят задавать время жизни объектов. Рассмотрим простой пример:

   ```
   public class A
   {
       public A(IB b, IC c) {}
   }

   public interface IB {}
   public class B 
   {
       public B(IC c) {}
   }

   public interface IC {}
   public class C {}
   ```

   В данном случае, при создании экземпляра типа А нам требуется экземпляр типа IB и IC, IB в свой очередь требует так же экземлпяр типа IС. Нам может потребоваться или создать в каждом случае новый экземпляр типа IC или исползовать в обоих случаях один и тот же. Контейнер позволяет легко этим манипулировать. Помимо этих двух случаев бывают еще и другие.
4. Позволяет применять перехват (interception). Это возможность с помощью контейнера встраивать какой-нибудь полезный код (типа логирования, проверки прав и т.п.) перед\после вызовов методов интерфейса зависимости. Об этом лучше почитать отдельно, с примерами, для конкретного контейнера. У Ninject для этого есть специальное [расширение](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception/wiki).

Comment: А мне наоборот установка через свойства чаще попадается. Но это так... Главное как происходит injection без фреймворка? Кто разбирает конфигурацию|аннотации, кто инжектит, если не фреймворк с контейнером?

Comment: Если нет фреймворка, то все надо делать вручную, естественно - создавать все необходимые объекты, инжектить их и возвращать результат. Поэтому контейнеры активно и используют, ибо на не совсем простых примерах делать что-то вручную требует больших усилий.

Comment: Значит в последнем абзаце ответа неправда написана. На самом деле фреймворк обязателен.

Comment: @banme а на счёт внедрения через конструктор или свойства обычно так: если зависимость обязательная, то через конструктор, если зависимость опциональный, то через свойство. Ещё можно через методы внедрять, по идее.

Comment: @banme нет, не обязателен. Просто с ним удобнее. Но если есть время или желание, то все можно сделать вручную ;) Как и с любым другим фреймворка, в принципе.

Answer (score 23):

Вот так может выглядеть внедрение зависимостей в реальном мире:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Розетка это ваш самурай, вилка - оружие. Между розеткой и вилкой есть интерфейс, который определяется габаритами штекера и напряжением сети. Может быть тысяча розеток и тысяча вилок, которые реализуют этот интерфейс и они будут совместимы между собой в любых комбинацих.

Когда вы внедряете зависимость через конструктор, вы создаете нечто аналогичное вилке с розеткой.

Далее. Работу над вашей программой можно (очень условно) разбить на две части:

1. Определение интерфейсов между компонентами и реализация этих компонентов (вы продумываете интерфейсы между вилками и розетками и создаете объекты, реализующие эти интерфейсы)
2. Сборка компонентов в работающую программу (вы садитесь и подключаете все между собой в определенном порядке)

Если вы сделаете так:

```
var samurai = new Samurai(new Sword());
```

то сборка будет размазана по всему вашему коду, у вас будут розетки, которые сами будут подключать к себе компоненты, это равносильно вот этому:

[image]

Когда вы используете контейнер внедрения зависимостей, вы выполняете сборку компонентов *вне самих компонентов* в одном месте, которое называется *корень компоновки*. Это то место, где вы пишете вот это:

```
this.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
```

В этом коде просто указывается какой объект надо использовать, когда требуется интерфейс `IWeapon`. В реальном приложении конфигурация будет сложнее. В ней будут инструкции, указывающие, что некоторые классы должны быть синглтонами, инструкции описывающие применение [декораторов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) в вашем проекте.

Вообще же DI это одна из тех концепций, которые только кажутся очень простыми и которые очень легко использовать неправильно. Точнее она действительно достаточно проста, но есть неочиведные нюансы, которые решают все и непонимание которых может обесценить ваш опыт ее применения, превратив его в культ Карго.

Поэтому очень рекомендую прочитать по этой теме как можно больше, одного ответа на so здесь явно недостаточно.

Answer (score 9):

> Окей, все хорошо, НО зачем нам нужен DI и дополнительные фреймворки, если мы можем сделать по сути тоже самое:
>
> ```
> var samurai = new Samurai(new Sword());
> ```

Это и есть Dependency Injection. Даже не используя никаких фреймворков, вы всё равно в этом примере использовали DI. Вы подали классу Samurai его зависимость при помощи инъекции этой зависимости в конструктор.

DI рекомендуется использовать всегда, вне зависимости от того, пользуетесь ли вы готовыми библиотеками или нет. Польза состоит в том, что классы, у которых есть зависимости (`Samurai`), не будут знать, где и каким образом эти зависимости получить. Они просто декларативно скажут: меня без этой зависимости (`IWeapon`) использовать нельзя.

Использование DI, даже без контейнеров, значительно уменьшает связанность кода. У ваших классов пропадают знания об инфрастуктуре вашего приложения и они становятся более независимыми, подчиняющимися принципам **SOLID**, тестируемыми и поддерживаемыми.

### Контр-пример

А теперь представьте, что вы *не* используете DI. Вместо этого используется какая-то разновидность антипаттерна **Service Locator** (я его здесь назвал `ConfigurationService`):

```
public class Samurai 
{
    public IWeapon Weapon { get; private set; }
    public Samurai() 
    {
        this.Weapon = ConfigurationService.Get<IWeapon>();
    }
}
```

Теперь, если вы в будущем решите применить IoC-контейнер, или же подавать зависимость в класс не через `ConfigurationService`, а каким-то другим способом, то вам придётся **изменять класс `Samurai`**. А что, если у вас в приложении десятки, сотни классов, которые используют этот Service Locator? Придётся изменять их все.

Когда используется паттерн Dependency Injection (как в вашем изначальном примере), при добавлении IoC-контейнера или изменения способа создания/получения зависимостей, сами классы, которые используют зависимости, **изменять не придётся**. В этом состоит огромная польза DI. Классы, использующие этот паттерн, не знают и не хотят знать об инфраструктуре приложения. Засчёт этого они более универсальны.

Comment: _"А что, если у вас в приложении десятки, сотни классов, которые используют этот Service Locator"_ -- также можно сказать, а что, если в Samurai понадобится передавать не только Sword, но еще и другие зависимости. Придется изменять все места вызовов new Samurai.

Comment: @Stack Вот именно. Явного создания новых объектов в коде также нужно избегать — как по приведённой вами причине, так и по соображениям абстрагирования от конкретных типов и стремления к работе с интерфейсами. Погуглите `new operator considered harmful`.

Comment: А вот мне непонятно объяснение. Вы говорите что если я захочу избавиться от SL то придётся изменить все классы где этот подход применялся. 
Точно также я могу сказать что если вы захотите избавиться от IOC контейнера, и захочу вернуться к SL, то придётся менять все классы. Тоесть не описание причина почему я ушёл от SL и чем он хуже.

Answer (score 1):

DI вещь удобна тем, что вы в **одном месте** можете описать фабрику-билдеров, которые создают нужные объекты, а затем при помощи аннотации в конструкторе или в полях классов связать их. Таким образом, если ваш объект принимает в конструкторе 10-к интерфейсов, то вы не будете писать длинную простыню и тянуть зависимости, а просто попросите DI-фреймворк создать нужный вам объект (если он не сможет разрулить зависимости, то он ругнется), что заметно повысит читаемость кода.
Однако у DI есть и оборотная сторона из-за которой я лично данный подход не использую - все эти не явные инициализации сильно затрудняют анализ кода (глядя на него нельзя сказать уверенно, какая реализация была передана), особенно это касается тех моментов, когда DI подход применяется не к конструктору, а к полям - тут наступает ад.

Comment: насчет ада я полностью согласен)