# Как изменить класс с вызовом библиотеки, чтобы использовать ЮнитТесты

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Есть класс, который внутри себя использует вызовы нативной библиотеки. Также внутри класса есть приватные и публичные методы.

```
class Matrix
{
    private List<IntPtr> _rows;

    [DllImport("MathCore.dll")]
    static private extern IntPtr CreateMatrixRow(string row);

    [DllImport("MathCore.dll")]
    static private extern IntPtr RemoveMatrixRow(int index);

    [DllImport("MathCore.dll")]
    static private extern void AddItem(IntPtr row, string name);

    [DllImport("MathCore.dll")]
    static private extern void RemoveItem(IntPtr row, string name);

    public Matrix(List<string> rows, string equation)
    {
        // some constructing
        ParseRows(rows);
        ParseEquation(equation);
    }

    private void ParseEquation(string equation)
    {
        // parse someIndex and someName
        AddItem(GetRow(someIndex), someName);
    }

    private void ParseRows(List<string> rows)
    {
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            _rows.Add(CreateMatrixRow(row));
        }
    }

    public int GetRowCount()
    {
        return _rows.Count;
    }

    public int GetRow(int index)
    {
        return _rows[index];
    }
}
```

Каким образом лучше всего разделить или изменить имплементацию так, чтобы можно было покрыть ЮнитТестами класс Matrix НЕ вызывая библиотеку MathCore.dll?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы хотите покрыть тестами вызовы из сторонней библиотеки, в частности `MathCore`?

Comment: Покрыть тестами сам класс без вызова MathCore. То есть как-то подменить экстерны на фейки. Понятно, что нужно разделить имплементацию, но непонятно как именно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, чтобы протестировать логику, заключенную непосредственно в классе `Matrix`, необходимо каким-то образом уметь "подменять" вызовы сторонней библиотеки своими значениями. Этого можно достичь несколькими способами:

- Вариант с абстрактным классом и переопределенными наследниками, который предложил @DreamChild. На мой взгляд, такой подход менее гибок. Например, для того, чтобы задать в тестах свои варианты возвращаемых значений из методов `ParseEquation`, `ParseRows`, придется либо создавать отдельных наследников для каждого набора возвращаемых значений, либо пользоваться частичными моками (partial mock), что не каждый мок-фреймворк умеет делать.
- Другой вариант -- выделить сторонний код в зависимость. Зависимость -- это некоторый объект, который будет передаваться внутрь класса `Matrix`. Одно из преимуществ такого подхода заключается в более легком тестировании -- отпадает необходимость создавать моки руками, все делается с помощью мок-фреймворка. Обзорно можно почитать в вопросе ["Зачем нужен Dependency Injection?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461814/), а углубиться в книге ["Внедрение зависимостей в .NET"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/22104901/).

  ```
  public interface IMathCore
  {
      IntPtr CreateMatrixRow(string row);

      IntPtr RemoveMatrixRow(int index);

      void AddItem(IntPtr row, string name);

      void RemoveItem(IntPtr row, string name);
  }

  public class MathCore : IMathCore
  {
      [DllImport("MathCore.dll")]
      static private extern IntPtr CreateMatrixRow(string row);

      [DllImport("MathCore.dll")]
      static private extern IntPtr RemoveMatrixRow(int index);

      [DllImport("MathCore.dll")]
      static private extern void AddItem(IntPtr row, string name);

      [DllImport("MathCore.dll")]
      static private extern void RemoveItem(IntPtr row, string name);

      public IntPtr CreateMatrixRow(string row)
      {
          return CreateMatrixRow(row);
      }

      // методы интерфейса вызывают сторонние методы
  }

  public class Matrix
  {
      private readonly IMathCore _mathCore;

      private List<IntPtr> _rows;

      public Matrix(List<string> rows, string equation)
          : this(new MathCore()) // реализация по умолчанию
      {
      }

      public Matrix(List<string> rows, string equation, IMathCore mathCore)
      {
          _mathCore = mathCore;
          // some constructing
          ParseRows(rows);
          ParseEquation(equation);
      }

      private void ParseEquation(string equation)
      {
          // parse someIndex and someName
          AddItem(GetRow(someIndex), someName);
      }

      private void ParseRows(List<string> rows)
      {
          foreach (var row in rows)
          {
              _rows.Add(_mathCore.CreateMatrixRow(row));
          }
      }

      public int GetRowCount()
      {
          return _rows.Count;
      }

      public int GetRow(int index)
      {
          return _rows[index];
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Можно из класса `Matrix` выделить абстрактный класс. В него вынести методы `ParseEquation`, `ParseRows` и прочие. При этом экспортируемые из библиотеки методы заменить на абстрактные с такими же сигнатурами и возвращаемыми значениями. Затем от этого класса унаследовать два других, не абстрактных. В первом объявить экспортируемые из библиотеки методы (с другими названиями, разумеется), а в унаследованных от предка и реализованных в этом классе абстрактных методах вызывать эти экспортируемые из библиотеки. 
Второй же наследник абстрактного класса не будет включать в себя экспортируемых из библиотеки методов, а в унаследованных от абстрактного класса методах вы можете написать какую-то тестовую реализацию и с помощью этого класса безболезненно тестировать бизнес-логику, заключенную в абстрактном классе