# Где и зачем нужно использовать Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger2

Сегодня на работе дали проект, Dagger там везде и повсюду! Ранее с этим не сталкивался, так как ни разу в этом не было необходимости. Я почитал интернет и понял, что это якобы *сахар* для тестирования и как бы в проекте все должно быть ровно и чисто.

Я очень долго всматривался в код и понимал, что это каша без сахара.
И что все то, что там написано, можно написать без Dagger гораздо компактнее, понятнее для всех и ведь **чем меньше площадь огорода - тем быстрее его можно пропахать**, это я про быстродействие приложения.

Приложение работает с апи, хранит данные в базе и там очень мало сложного *ui* с анимациями. Но везде есть Rx! Прям везде, даже там где этого не требуется... зачем!?
Этот проект во-первых долго собирается, как бы я не гуглил на эту тему, все безуспешно.
Абсолютно никакущая структура приложения, вообще далекая от *clean*.
Непонятные *inject*ы *activity* - зачем? Android уже имеет все инструменты для старта активности. Класс *Application* уже *singleton* и непонятно зачем Dagger предлагает делать тоже самое.

Я абсолютно не понимаю зачем нужен Dagger? Какой проект обязательно должен быть построен с его использованием? Или это просто очередная *фишка*, которую впихнули в проект в погоне за модными штучками?

Я точно уверен, что Dagger был лишним в том проекте и я его переписал без его использования. Код стал гораздо чище и приложение стало в разы быстрее.

Comment: Можно вопрос, сколько экранов было в этом приложении? Потому что, приложение на 30+ полноценных экранов писать без DI просто не представляю как. И да, начинать вход в DI лучше с чего-то по-проще. Это Toothpick, либо Koin; вообще вариантов много. Ну и просьба добавить в вопрос информацию о том, какой вообще стек технологий в приложении, количество экранов. Ну и на счет Rx. Это не серебряная пуля, но вещь шикарная, если уметь пользоваться.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov как понять не представляю? У того приложения 4 основных экрана, каждый в глубину по +2-3. Отлично написался на простых фрагментах. И очень убого выглядел на Di. Rx хорош в нужных мечтах же, а когда его пихают прям для каждого метода... ну это я считаю паранойя уже. Рассскажите пожалуйста в ответе или тут, почему на 30+ экранов это не реально, я очень хочу увидеть аргументы в его пользу. Повторюсь, я начитался уже в инете про это.

Comment: Вы правы в том, что очень часто в разработке используются какие-то инструменты, просто потому, что надо и все. Тренд такой. Если вы не видите для себя преимуществ, то лучшее, что можно сделать - отказаться от использования такого инструмента и не мучать себя. Единственное, что должно быть, это вы должны вполне понимать, что какой-то конкретный инструмент делает, чтобы в случае, когда его использование оправдано - применить.

Comment: Покажу похожий пример. С появлением RecyclerView очень от многих можно слышать, что это супер и ListView в помойку. Я пытался как-то объективно обозначить разницу и ниши каждого виджета в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/604908/177345), но как видно из голосов, "невидимая рука рынка" не в пользу здравого смысла. Принят и имеет более в два раза больше голосов ответ, в котором описано, как крут и мощен RecyclerView, что мы можем и так вертеть и этак. Даже когда нам этого и не надо. Тренды.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В комментариях я несколько погорячился на счет "нереально" написать приложение на 30+ экранов без DI библиотеки. Хороший тому пример - телеграмм, в их приложении под Android нет никакого стороннего DI. Возможно, есть что-то самописное, не изучал код сколько-нибудь тщательно.

Однако DI библиотеки все еще остаются чрезвычайно важной штукой, потому что:

1. *Понятность*. **Любой** Android-разработчик с опытом работы более двух лет имеет опыт работы со сторонним DI. Причем абсолютное большинство знакомо с Dagger. Сегодня над проектом работаете Вы. Завтра Вы уволитесь и работать будет другой человек. С Dagger'ом он разберется точно (и найдет тысячи подсказок в интернете). А с Вашим решением?
2. *Тестирование*. То о чем Вы читали в интернете. Тестировать с DI на порядок проще, чем без него. А если Вы не пишете тесты, то это плохо. Ну либо Ваши приложения достаточно простые. Либо Вы гений, который не ошибается.
3. *Clean.* Та самая чистая архитектура, которую Вы упомянули в вопросе. Для ее построения нужно использование принципа **Dependency Inversion**. Для использования которого, в свою очередь, есть только один действительно распространенный подход - **Dependency Injection**. А дальше у Вас выбор: изобрести велосипед, или взять готовый. И Dagger относительно терпимый готовый вариант. (*Личное мнение: На мой взгляд только мазохист выберет Dagger, если он ранее использовал Koin или Toothpick и выбор вообще есть)*

Теперь немножко сбоку от темы вопроса.

- По поводу быстродействия приложения. Это не главное. И даже не второе. И даже не третье по степени важности. Приложение должно быть **достаточно** быстрым, чтобы не доставлять дискомфорт. Не более. Потому что куда важнее, например, чтобы приложение было **как можно более** быстрым в разработке и модификации. В том числе силами разработчиков, которые это приложение раньше никогда не видели. А еще важнее, чтобы приложение было красивым. А еще важно, чтобы оно не падало почти совсем никогда. И вот только потом идет быстродействие приложения. И то не факт. Поэтому нужно избегать изобретения велосипедов. В Вашей быстрой системе кому-то потом разбираться (и, вероятно, переписывать с нуля).

  > Нужно понимать, что сказанное в абзаце выше не касается сверхкрупных приложений, разрабатываемых сотнями разработчиков. Там вообще все важно.
- Вот этот момент остался мне несколько непонятным:

  > Приложение работает с апи, хранит данные в базе и там очень мало сложного ui с анимациями. Но везде есть Rx!

  Я использую Rx во всех проектах почти два года. И вообще ни разу не использовал его для работы с анимациями. Либо я, либо Вы что-то не знаем об Rx. Но я точно знаю, где отлично работает RX: это работа с сетью, с базой данных, обработка данных и многое другое. А еще он очень удобен для работы с ui (от самого простого до сложного без ограничений). Да, он значительно медленнее, чем работа без него. Но божечки, какой же он удобный!
- Вот это

  > проект во-первых долго собирается

  Конечно, проблема. Но не большая. Пример с работы. Приложение около 70 сложных разнообразных экранов, нетривиальная логика работы с данными, множество связей между экранами во все стороны (такая логика затребована бизнесом). Проект на холодную собирается минут 5-7. На горячую - от 5 секунд, в зависимости от количества изменений с последней сборки. И да, у нас все в Rx. И все на DI.
- А это уже просто вина предыдущего разработчика. DI  должен помогать создавать Clean, у кого-то просто руки были из одного места, не повезло Вам с наследием.

  > Абсолютно никакущая структура приложения, вообще далекая от clean.
- А вот тут бы я поспорил.

  > Класс Application уже singleton и непонятно зачем Dagger предлагает делать тоже самое.

  Количество проблем, полученных в результате неправильной работы с `Application`, не сосчитать. Да хоть те же утечки памяти от сохраненных в нем ссылок на `Activity`. Вы, вполне возможно, не совершили ни одной такой ошибки. Но зачем рисковать?
- Вот тут

  > очередная фишка, которую впихнули в проект в погоне за модными штучками?

  Вы несколько неправы. Хотя, это, конечно, зависит от времени написания проекта. Но сейчас Dagger скорее выходит из моды будучи уже отработавшим своё старым-добрым другом. Его популярность снижается.
- Ну и постараюсь ответить на, наверное, главный вопрос:

  > Какой проект обязательно должен быть построен с его [Dagger] использованием?

  Ответ: никакой. Пять минут на гугление и Вы найдете десяток достойных замен. Но Вы не построите нормальный проект без DI. Пусть он будет самописный, но в крупном проекте он будет. Либо проект не случится. Либо Вы гений и изобрели то, до чего никто из разработчиков за 50 лет не додумался.

Ну и некоторая информация к размышлению. Для того, чтобы понять смысл DI и Rx с ними надо поработать. Минимум пол года. Каждый день в полноформатном 8 - часовом режиме. Это чисто из личного опыта и бесед с коллегами. Где-то после этого начинаешь что-то понимать. Быстрее из моих знакомых никто не освоил. Но это те знания, которые действительно нужны. И это не новомодные вещи. Это, в сущности, инструменты для создания действительно Clean проектов. Есть и другие инструменты. Но на сегодняшний день почти все используют DI и почти половина - Rx. И так далеко не первый год. Так что вещи проверенные.

Что-то слишком простыня получилась, ну и ладно. Постараюсь отвечать на доп вопросы, если Вы зададите их в комментариях в меру своих знаний и сил.

P.s.

Схожий вопрос уже задавался на ruSO [Зачем-нужен-dependency-injection-контейнер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461814/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-dependency-injection-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80)

А еще есть небольшая, но полезная статься на [Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/321344/)

Comment: да, спасибо, вроде исчерпывающе. я действительно ни разу не работал с di и может этот момент настал и пора разбираться. тогда из вашего личного опыта, что может быть лучше dagger?

Comment: @Сергей как я и писал, по моему личному мнению лучше всех сейчас Toothpick и Koin. Toothpick проще и почти совсем не требует дополнительного кода. Для начала, на мой взгляд, он идеален.

Comment: поговаривают Koin это ServiceLocator (например, Jake Wharton так говорит), а не DI, но сам с ним не работал и не разбирался. Есть ещё Kodein, но тоже вроде SL

Comment: @IR42 Вы правы, к ServerLocator Koin ближе. Но на мой взгляд, это не принципиально. Toothpick, кстати, тоже, не совсем DI, он где-то по середине. [Статейка](https://habr.com/ru/post/321344/) на эту тему.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov вероятный плюс от Di вижу только, например на spring boot сервере где тысячи юзеров и каждый просит данные своего профиля или сохранить что-то в базу (тоесть создавая кучи объектов).

Comment: спасибо за ссылки. это действительно полезно для меня. возможно спустя полгода кодинга di я наконец пойму все его прелести... но сейчас я все же ярый противник этого)

Comment: Ещё Hilt. Согласен, что это мазохизм. Про 5 секунд какие-то невероятные вещи, даже если там многомодульность. Обычно Dagger добавляет некоторое время к компиляции, и оно больше 5 секунд, так что в целом получается от минуты.