# Каким образом DI контейнер снабжает классы сервисами?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-core, di

Такой вопрос. Может кто нибудь объяснить как работает DI контейнер в .net? Допустим, я хочу реализовать ioc для nunit тестов: как должен выглядеть DI контейнер? И как правильно создавать экземпляры нужных мне классов, чтобы в их конструкторы автоматически передавались нужные сервисы? В .net core framework объявление экземпляров классов (контроллеров, например) скрыто где-то в дебрях промежуточного ПО, по этому я не совсем понимаю как все это работает. Как именно сервисы попадают в конструкторы? И как можно это повторить в другом проекте, чтобы можно было автоматизировать передачу сервисов в конструкторы, как в фреймворке?
Буду благодарен за любую инфу.

Comment: Почитайте об инверсии зависимостей, а потом про DI. То о чем вы пишете - встроенный DI в .NET ASP, а не весь .net core framework. Есть сторонние DI например "Autofac" его можно юзать как в том же ASP, так и в других видах приложений. Про DI есть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461814/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-dependency-injection-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80/463654#463654)

Comment: `реализовать ioc для nunit тестов` - так не надо, юнит тесты не должны нуждаться в DI контейнере по идее

Comment: [марк симан внедрение зависимостей в .net](https://www.ozon.ru/product/vnedrenie-zavisimostey-v-net-22104901/?sh=Ebo7hpKy) хорошо объясняет

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался. В основном, благодаря хорошей документации от autofac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос о принципе работы, то к примеру у вас есть 2 класса

```cs
public class Settings
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    private readonly Settings _settings;

    public Worker(Settings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}
```

Если без контейнера, то запустить всю эту систему весьма просто

```cs
var settigns = new Settings();
var worker = new Worker(settings);
```

Но допустим у вас есть абстрактный контейнер, я возьму синтаксис только что придуманного мной. У него есть билдер `ContainerBuilder` с обобщенным методом `Register`, и есть он сам `Container` с обобщенным методом `Resolve`.

Тогда выше показанный код будет выглядеть так.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register<Settings>();
builder.Register<Worker>();

var container = builder.Build();
var worker = container.Resolve<Worker>();
```

Здесь видно, что вся работа с контейнером разделяется на 2 этапа: регистрация типов и получение экземпляров.

Теперь сама суть контейнера, его смысл. Вам не нужно на этапе создания экземпляров в коде явно указывать, какой экземпляр нужно передать куда в конструктор. То есть при работе с контейнером нет зависимости от изменений кода в классах. Всё что нужно - это зарегистрировать типы, и оно само заработает.

Внутри это работает так: контейнер через рефлексию ищет доступный конструктор и смотрит типы его аргументов. Далее он смотрит у себя, есть ли среди зарегистрированных типов нужные? Если да, то он создает экземпляр нужного типа и далее просто вызывает конструктор используя только созданный экземпляр для передачи в аргумент. Это называется Dependency Injection (DI), а именно Constructor Injection. Если зарегистрированного типа не найдено, контейнер просто бросит исключение и ничего не создаст.

Конечно всё намного сложнее в популярных контейнерах устроено, но смысл инверсии управления тот же. Управление созданием экземпляров автоматизировано внутри контейнера, вы сами в коде ничего не создаете.

Когда у вас 10 типов в приложении - можно легко обойтись без контейнера. А когда 1000, то можно легко запутаться, или изменения в одном классе могут повлечь требования доработок в 50 других классов. Контейнер дает больше свободы при внесении изменений в код.

Когда-то я сам разбирался с этим вопросом здесь: [IoC в MVVM для чайников](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1184712/373567)